# How do I make this popup code cleaner?

Tags: javascript, html

This is how I'm currently creating a popup for a few links on my site.

```
function popitup(url) {
  newwindow=window.open(url,'name','height=615,width=475');
  if (window.focus) {newwindow.focus()}
}
```

`<a href="song-lyrics.txt" onclick="return popitup('song-lyrics.txt')"></a>`

Is there a cleaner way to write this? Also, how do I make the scrollbar appear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure to change `newwindow=` to `var newwindow=`; otherwise you are declaring a global variable every time you run this function.

Otherwise, I agree with fsong's answer that it's a pretty basic function and doesn't need much cleaning. Here's what I would do, but it's minor stuff:

```
function popItUp(url) {
    var newWindow = window.open(url, 'name', 'height=615,width=475,scrollbars=yes');

    if (newWindow.focus) {
        newWindow.focus();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what you mean by a cleaner way, the code seems fairly straight forward to me. But you could get rid of the `return` in the onclick of the anchor tag since it's useless there and perhaps you could use underscore/camel case to name your function (`pop_it_up` or `popItUp`) for better readability.

For scrollbars add `,scrollbars=yes` to the last parameter (strWindowFeatures) in window.open.

Answer (score 1):

### JSLint

I would check your code through [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/).

> JSLint is a JavaScript program that looks for problems in JavaScript
>   programs. It is a code quality tool.

Like author says JSLint will hurt your feelings, but I think the error you should certainly fix is:

```
Problem at line 2 character 3: 'newwindow' was used before it was defined.
```

This is issue exactly like Domenic said.

When you check your code with JSLint your code will also have better success when using tools like [Javascript Minifier](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/jsmin.html).

### Make Javascript external

I also think you should [make Javascript and CSS external](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#external).

> Using external files in the real world generally produces faster pages
>   because the JavaScript and CSS files are cached by the browser.
>   JavaScript and CSS that are inlined in HTML documents get downloaded
>   every time the HTML document is requested. This reduces the number of
>   HTTP requests that are needed, but increases the size of the HTML
>   document. On the other hand, if the JavaScript and CSS are in external
>   files cached by the browser, the size of the HTML document is reduced
>   without increasing the number of HTTP requests.

I think you should read Yahoo!'s best practices, because it has a lot of very good tips to optimize your website(javascript).

### Why popups?

But Why should you use popups? Some users block these, which renders your site unusable. I would advice you to use [JQuery](http://jquery.com/) and just [load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) content into the DOM.